# YUI3 Datatable How to implement server side pagination.

Tags: datatable, pagination, yui3

I'm currently working on a school project where we need to display database info in a web UI.

I have a YUI3 Datatable with built in client side pagination. Now I would like to implement server side pagination due to the massive amount of data I will have to work with.

**Are there any good solid tutorials on how to implement server side pagination in YUI3?**

I've already gone through the API and the YUI2 tutorials I've come across have features no longer supported in YUI3..

Answer (score 1):

No, not that I can find.

I've used [this paginator](http://stlsmiths.github.io/new-gallery/classes/Y.DataTable.Paginator.html) with great success. But the documentation that did exist seems to have vanished both from the github repo and from http://blunderalong.com/yui/gallery/datatable-paginator/paginator_examples.html where it used to live. It may be worth pinging the author a message about it.

Answer (score 1):

Like barnyr, I've used Todd Smith's paginator with great success. I agree that the closest you can get to a tutorial is by perusing Todd's comments in the code.

When I pinged Todd with a fix for a resizing problem, he responded that he had stopped working on it. I guess it's up to us to figure it out now. Also, he seemed to believe that YUI must have either picked up his code from the gallery or developed an equivalent solution; neither seems to be the case right now.

It is sad that blunderalong is gone -- it had lots of goodies -- but I have Todd's server-side pagination example fossilised in my repo:

https://github.com/selkovjr/bfs/blob/master/mojits/Samples/binders/index.js

And here is the server-side model that provides the data for it:

https://github.com/selkovjr/bfs/blob/master/mojits/Samples/models/samples.server.js

It is a bigger pile than you're asking for (the binder code also has row selection and inline cell editing), but at least it has the example you're looking for, almost unchanged.

Answer (score 0):

We are still using YUI 2 which is really good large amounts of data.

Try http://yui.github.io/yui2/docs/yui_2.9.0_full/examples/datatable/dt_dynamicdata.html

and it might be good to do SQL sort for heavy loads which is cheaper.

Answer (score 0):

You can try following examples

http://jafl.github.io/yui-modules/querybuilder/ for complete datatable implementation 
 or http://jafl.github.io/yui-modules/paginator/ for different pagination samples.

I have implemented paginator successfully using this example.